# Alternative proof that the sum of two convergent series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

For my Real Analysis course I'm being asked to prove this basic concept:

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|$ converge absolutely then prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_n)$ also converges absolutely.

Now this question is very basic. It can be proved by adapting the proof of the sum law for limits to series instead. I've done this but my professors says the answer is wrong. Instead, he wants to me solve this question without using epsilon-proofs. The only hint he provides is that I must consider the rearrangement of each series and apply the triangle inequality to prove convergence. This logic is incomprehensible to me but he refuses to help any further.

Is there another method to prove this question without using limit laws and epsilon-proofs?

Comment: He wants you to use $|a_n+b_n|\le|a_n|+|b_n|$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what he mentioned. The issue is that I don't understand the logic for how $|a_n+b_n|\le|a_n|+|b_n|$ can be used to prove convergence without the use of limit laws and epsilon-delta.

Comment: Last hint: $|a_n+b_n|\ge0$.

Comment: If $|a_n+b_n|\ge0$ then $|a_n|+|b_n|\ge0$ since $|a_n+b_n|\le|a_n|+|b_n|$. How exactly does lead to a conclusion that the sum of two convergent series is convergent? All we've done is state that both sides of inequality are greater than zero.

Comment: This is not how you must exploit the hint.

Comment: Okay, then how do I exploit the hint? I don't see the logic

Comment: Read my comment to Shaqinho's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, we only want to show that
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert a_n + b_n \rvert < \infty.
$$
By the triangle inequality we have:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert a_n + b_n \rvert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\lvert a_n \rvert + \lvert b_n \rvert)
$$
Since both
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert a_n \rvert \quad \text{ and } \quad \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert b_n \rvert
$$
converge, we can rewrite
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\lvert a_n \rvert + \lvert b_n \rvert) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert a_n \rvert + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert b_n \rvert < \infty.
$$
So
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert a_n + b_n \rvert < \infty
$$
according to the direct comparison test.

In general: If we can prove that some series $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert c_n \rvert$ is bounded, we know (at least in $\mathbb{R}$) that it converges, since the partial sums
$$
S_m: m \mapsto \sum_{n = 1}^m \lvert c_n \rvert
$$
are [bounded and increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers). To see the latter just note that ($m \in \mathbb{N})$:
$$
0 \leq \lvert a_{m+1} - b_{m+1} \rvert \implies S_m \leq S_{m} + \lvert a_{m+1} - b_{m+1} \rvert = S_{m+1}
$$

Comment: This proof is incomplete. You only prove that the sum is bounded.

Comment: Depends on how you look at it... So we know that the sequence $\left( \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^m \lvert a_n + b_n \rvert \right)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. It is obviously increasing. But then it must have a limit as $m \rightarrow  \infty$, too. I assume that he knows this. At least I am sure that you know it...

Comment: Perhaps most other students would know these basic concepts, but I do not. So further explanation is always nice.

Comment: "obviously increasing" is missing. A student would get an F with such an answer. (For ordinary people, you might just say that the series is "obviously convergent".)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I guess this would depend on the school... But we can prove that, too: Because the absolute value is never negative, we know $0 \leq \lvert a_{m+1} - b_{m+1} \rvert$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Add $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^m \lvert a_n + b_n \rvert$ to both sides of the inequality to get $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^m \lvert a_n + b_n \rvert \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{m+1} \lvert a_n + b_n \rvert$, i.e. that the series is increasing.

Comment: @Shaqinho: you needn't tell me. This must be said in the proof. (Though I have no idea why you refer to $|a_{m+1}-b_{m+1}|$.)

Comment: On another note: I mentioned the direct comparison test. It actually does say that if we can bound the partial sums by absolutely convergent ones, the original series converges. But yes, I unfortunately do not quite know which theorems have been presented in @Dylan 's class.

Comment: The question is about absolute convergence. IMO the OP is just meant to invoke an increasing and bounded sequence.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe @Dylan can tell us if he knows the comparison test...

Comment: @Shaqinho I am familiar with the comparison test. I've used it plenty of times in Calculus to prove that a series is convergent. I do believe the purpose of this question was to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_n)$ is increasing and bounded therefore it is absolutely convergent. In my course, we're presented with all the abstract proofs for the standard tests for convergent along with the Rearrangement Theorem. This is certainly basic stuff but I struggle with the basics hence the purpose of asking math stack.

Comment: From my understanding of your proof, it seems like the triangle inequality was a method to set up a comparison test. We know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|$ converge, so therefore anything less than or equal to them would converge as well. We use the triangle inequaliy then to create a upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_n)$ so it may converge. I think the only part I'm confused with now is how the setup triangle inequality can be used to prove it the series is increasing

Comment: "Comparison test" comes from "bounded and increasing", which I wanted to explain in the last paragraph of my answer. Yes, the triangle inequality is used to find the upper bound. The partial sums being increasing is much more basic and has nothing to do with the triangle inequality: It comes down to "just adding positive stuff".

Comment: No, the comparison test has nothing to do with monotonicity of the sequence. For instance you can very well squeeze alternating sequences.

Answer (score 1):

1. The series is bounded above, as $\sum|a_n+b_n|\le\sum |a_n|+\sum|b_n|$.
2. The series forms an increasing sequence, as every term $|a_n+b_n|$ is non-negative.